# Sidekiq + Rails 6.0.0 in API mode : WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently trying to setup a standalone rails 6.0.0 API fresh install (rails new xxx --api) + sidekiq (that includes Rack::Protection)

After setting-up Rack::Cors, i get the following 403 error on any non-GET request :

> WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::AuthenticityToken

To my understanding this is related to CSRF tokens, which don't make sense for a json API.

Here is a copy of the request I'm doing :

> curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5100/searches' -H 'Accept: application/json,
>   text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:8080/' -H 'Origin:
>   http://localhost:8080' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' -H
>   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data '{query:
>   'test'}' --compressed

The 2 possible solutions that I cannot solve :

- disable rack-protection
- get a token in a controller (ActionController::API) to pass to the requests

Answer (score 1):

In ApplicationController try `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`, or 
  `Rails.configuration.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
      origins "*"
    end
  end`
 in config/initializers/rack-cors.rb

Comment: Thanks but no luck, protect_from_forgery is not defined in ActionController::API (and the request is blocked by rack, before reaching the controller), and no change with the updated cors configuration

Comment: Try something like this post :payment, :csrf_protection => false in routes.rb

Comment: routes.rb is called after rack